# UiBinder: call method on an object you bind to

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to call a method on the object you are binding to?

For example, I want to define a button in my layout and decide if it's visible at runtime. So I need to call a method `isMyButtonVisible()` on object I bind to.

```
<my:Button ui:field="btnBenchmark" title="Benchmark" 
     visible="{isMyButtonVisible}" />
```

Comment: make is visible pro-grammatically. You can access the button in java code using `@UiField`

Comment: Yes, that's my current solution. But I find method call a better alternative.

Comment: Why do you need `isMyButtonVisible()` if there is `isVisible()`? Setting the visibility of `myButton` according to it's current visibility state sounds wrong to me. Anyways, what you can do is calling a method of an object defined with <ui:with...>.

Comment: Right now there is no way to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480214/how-to-add-properly-uihandler-for-blurevent-in-gwt/26493742#26493742

Comment: I think the closest you could get to this would be using a @UiConstructor for type button.

Comment: @z00bs, this method determines if the button will be visible or not. The result of the method will set the visible attribute of the button

Answer (score 0):

You can pass constructor parameters in uibinder
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget